# Select a Date Difference inside a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

below is part of a LINQ statement i have where i'm trying to cast a property in my DTO to a new date,  that Date being the number of Days (if any), hours and minutes from a start date of right now (DateTime.Now or something similar) to a date pulled from SQL Server.

```
select new ATSRequestDto
                    {
                        ATSRequestID = atsr.ATSRequestID,
                        CreatedDate = atsr.CreatedDt,
                        Desciption = atsr.Description,
                        Priority = c.Description,
                        DepartmentName = laststatus.Department.Name,
                        DepartmentID = laststatus.Department.DepartmentID,
                        Status = laststatus.Code.Description,
                        IsClosed = atsr.IsClosed,

                        LastStatusDateDiff = laststatus.CreatedDt - DateTime.Now    // right here

                    };
```

i could probably figure out how to do this without this being in the cast,  just don't know how to do it inside the cast..    Thanks for your help

Comment: What cast are you talking about?  What specifically is wrong with your current code?

Comment: What exacly is the data type of `LastStatusDateDiff `?  Is it a `DateTime` (as you refer in you question), or a `TimeSpan` (which is th enatural type of a difference between dates) ?

Comment: I made it a TimeSpan and that worked..     Now i'm bringing it back to a Grid and it doesn't show correctly.

Comment: Then try this myTimeSpan.ToString("dd'd 'hh'h 'mm'm'") You get something like 01d 10h 59m. This format is perhaps more clear "dd'days 'hh'hours 'mm'minutes'" returns 01days 10hours 59minutes

Comment: Where do i put this code derloopkat.?

Comment: Actually,  that worked quite well derloopkat,  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on your question.

Can you do
LastStatusDateDiff = laststatus.CreatedDt.Date - DateTime.Now

or
LastStatusDateDiff = DateTime.ParseExact(laststatus.CreatedDt, "yyyyMMDD") - DateTime.Now